# Is it possible to delete a single value in the shared cache of an IgniteRDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, ignite

Is it possible to remove a specific item from the Ignite shared cache (IgniteRDD)?

For example, in the following code, how could you remove the only item (21, 21)?

```
val cacheRdd = igniteContext.fromCache("partitioned")

cacheRdd.savePairs(sparkContext.parallelize(1 to 10000, 10).map(i => (i, i)))
```

IgniteRDD provides a method called `clear()` that removes all content from the cache. Is there something similar to remove a specific item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know several ways to do it:

1)Using SQL delete command

```
val cacheRdd = igniteContext.fromCache("Person")

val result = cacheRdd.sql(
  "DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE ID=1")
```

2)Using JCache API:

```
// Creates Ignite context with specific configuration and runs Ignite in the embedded mode.
JavaIgniteContext<Integer, Integer> igniteContext = new JavaIgniteContext<Integer, Integer>(
    sparkContext,"examples/config/spark/example-shared-rdd.xml", false);

IgniteCache<Long, Person> personIgniteCache = igniteContext.ignite().getOrCreateCache("Person");

personIgniteCache.remove(1L);
```

The same from scala:

```
val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sparkContext, CONFIG, false)

igniteContext.ignite().getOrCreateCache("Person");
```

You also can just start Ignite node in your driver application.

BR,
Andrei

Comment: Thank you! I have one question related with the second way to do it. If I use JCache, will the behavior of the operations I do on the cache be the same as if I use an RDD? That is, if I do a cache.foreach () will it run distributed?

Comment: Not really. IgniteRDD is the distributed 
data stored in Spark that can be stored to the Ignite cluster using an internal data streamer. IgniteCache instance is the proxy interface of Ignite cache that can be used to make operation on it. IgniteRdd used IgniteContext inside. IgniteContext includes the instance of Ignite client that used by this RDD to make distributed operations in Ignite cluster. So both features (IgniteRDD and IgniteCache) will produce the distributed operation under Ignite Cache. But they will do it using different mechanisms.